# wlan0 interface disabled at startup on raspberry / debian

Tags: debian, wpa-supplicant, wlan, wpa-cli

At boot of my Raspbian (Debian 10) I have this:

```
$ sudo wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.8-devel
Copyright (c) 2004-2019, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'

Interactive mode

> status
wpa_state=INTERFACE_DISABLED
p2p_device_address=de:a6:32:32:e9:32
address=de:a6:32:32:e9:32
uuid=622a44c0-abb5-576f-93be-bd05478ea3b2
> scan
FAIL
```

I can activate the wifi only with the desktop interface / mouse.
Everytime I reboot I have to activate it manually.

Any hint about how to activate it on boot?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
$ iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Failed to read scan data : Network is down

$ sudo rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

$ sudo rfkill unblock all
$ sudo rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Solved